# Zip script using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a line in my bash script that will take all the subdirectories that exist in the working directory that are older than 7 days and zip them up into one zip file, then delete those subdirectories.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite you command as:

```sh
find $WORK_DIR \
  -type d \
  -mtime +7 \
  -exec bash -c "zip -q -m -j -J $WORK_DIR/$NEWZIP.zip {} && rm -rf {}" \;
```

Where `{}` is the file (directory) name placeholder.

Comment: When you say file name placeholder, which file is that referring to?

Comment: The name of the directory found by the `find` command.

Comment: You will want to single-quote the directory name to avoid errors with names with spaces, e.g. `'{}'` The same for `$WORK_DIR` in the `find` command.